# Como atualizar <audio> html sem precisar dar refresh na pagina inteira?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Minha pagina web deve tocar um audio diferente a cada 1 minuto, sem dar refresh na pagina inteira. O audio pode ficar em uma div, mas ele precisa ser atualizado a cada 1 minuto, mas da forma que está, o navegador sempre pega o primeiro audio tocado, e sempre que mudo o audio e salvo o arquivo, o navegador sempre pega audio pelo qual a pagina foi carregado a ultima vez.

Resumindo, preciso atualizar o audio em uma div.

Segue meu código:

HTML E PHP

```
<?php

include("config/conn.php");
$seguntos=2; //segundos
?>  

<audio id="audio" style="display:none">
<source src="sons/aero.wav" type="audio/wav" /> <!--esse arquivo é modificado faço isso manual mesmo e salvo o arquivo, mas irei automatizar isso -->
</audio>
```

FUNÇÃO JAVASCRIPT AUDIO

```
<script type="text/javascript">

audio = document.getElementById('audio');

function play(){
audio.play();
audio.stop();
audio.pause();
}

</script>
```

FUNÇÃO JAVASCRIPT VERIFICA A SITUAÇÃO E DA O PLAY

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function atualizar()
    {
        $.post('atualizapainel.php', function (paciente) {
            $('#paciente').html('<b>' + paciente.nome_paciente + '</b><br />');
            $('#local').html('<b>' + paciente.situacao + '</b><br />');

            if (paciente.situacao == 'EM ATENDIMENTO')  {
                play();

            } 
            paciente.situacao=1;
        }, 'JSON');
    }

    setInterval("atualizar()",  <?php echo $seguntos*30000; ?>); // Valor em milissegundos
    $(function() {
        atualizar();

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pagina do audio**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
   update();
   play()
});

function update(){
setInterval(
    function() {
       //pega o valor do input a ser enviado via post para atualizaAudio.php
       var num = $("#idInput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "atualizaAudio.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {numAudio: num},
            success: function(n){
               //n é composto de uma url do audio mais o caractere | mais um numero
               //exemplo to_nem_ai.mp3|1
              //separamos o rtetorno da requisição dado por n
              var res = n.split("|");
              //aqui setamos o novo valor para o input dado por res[1]
              document.getElementById("idInput").value = res[1];
              //conteudo atualizado da div que contem o audio, setando o src do audio para o novo valor dado por res[0]
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<audio id="audio"><source id="qqid" src="'+res[0]+'" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
              play();

            }
        });

    },

15000);
}

</script>

<input id="idInput" type="hidden" value="0">

<div id="demo">
<audio id="audio">
<source id="qqid" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/bigger-picture.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
function play(){
var x = document.getElementById("audio"); 
   x.play();
}
</script>
```

**atualizaAudio.php**

```
//vindo via post
$numAudio=$_POST['numAudio'];

//array auxiliar com mumeração igual a quantidade de audios
$numero = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

//condicional que incrementa a variável $numAudio até a quantidade de áudios no array 
$numAudio < 4 ? $numAudio++ : $numAudio=1;

//seta o audio de acordo com a variável $numAudio
switch ($numAudio) {
    case 1:
        $audio="tarantella.mp3";
        break;
    case 2:
        $audio="esera.mp3";
        break;
    case 3:
        $audio="deo.mp3";
        break;
    case 4:
        $audio="to_nem_ai.mp3";
        break;
    default:
        $audio="https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/bigger-picture.mp3";
}

//resultado a passar para processar na pagina do audio
echo $audio."|".$numAudio;
```

> Como desenvolvedor, você pode alterar o comportamento da política de reprodução automática do Google Chrome localmente para testar seu website.

Pode optar por desativar completamente a política de reprodução automática, definindo o sinalizador do Chrome *"Autoplay Policy"* para *"No user gesture is required"* em chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy . Isso permite que você teste seu website como se o usuário estivesse fortemente envolvido com seu site e a reprodução automática sempre fosse permitida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Alterações na Política de Reprodução Automática](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=pt-BR&sl=en&tl=pt&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fweb%2Fupdates%2F2017%2F09%2Fautoplay-policy-changes&anno=2) (ingles)

[Google tradutor - Alterações na Política de Reprodução Automática](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fweb%2Fupdates%2F2017%2F09%2Fautoplay-policy-changes&edit-text=&act=url)

Answer (score 0):

Sem fazer refresh na página, você precisa atualizar todo o elemento `audio`.

Faça o seguinte, inclua o `audio` em um `span` com um `id`:

```
<span id="audiocontainer" style="display:none">
   <audio id="audio">
      <source src="sons/aero.wav" type="audio/wav" />
   </audio>
</span>
```

Na função `play()`, altere o HTML do `span` com o próprio HTML, fazendo com que o navegador puxe novamente o arquivo `wav`, mas é preciso também modificar o nome do arquivo. Não precisa alterar o nome original, basta acrescentar um parâmetro qualquer para que o navegador pense que é um novo arquivo, algo como `sons/aero.wav?12321321`.

Para gerar esse parâmetro você pode usar a data do sistema. Veja o código:

```
audio = document.getElementById('audio');

function play(){
   var src = "sons/aero.wav";
   var param = new Date().getTime();
   src += "?"+param;
   $("#audio source").attr("src", src);
   $("#audiocontainer").html($("#audiocontainer").html());

   audio.play();
   audio.stop();
   audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: Essa tag audio não funciona com style="display:none"  e nem reproduz automaticamente no Chrome e no Opera. No Safari não funciona nada.

Comment: pq vc negativou minha resposta?

Comment: Foi eu não.. rss

Comment: Já que não foi vc, pq vc acha que negativaram? veja perguta do AP `Minha pagina web deve tocar um audio diferente a cada 1 minuto, sem dar refresh na pagina inteira.`

Comment: Xiii, acho que descobri, era pra ser 1 minuto e botei 15 segundos, aff

Comment: Não faço ideia. Tem gente por aí que sai negativando mesmo.

Comment: Já percebi isso, tenho pena deles!